# Is adding encryption before hashing more secure?

Tags: encryption, passwords, hash, salt

One way to secure a password in the database is to hash it with salt i.e. appending a random string to the password and then hash it and store the value.

Does encrypting the `password || salt` then hashing it make it more secure? Is it really necessary (or can I skip the encryption part)?

Comment: "Is it necessary?" Since it is your own invention and not the standard process, you can safely conclude that it is not *necessary*.

Comment: @schroeder but hashing itself is non-reversible. Just thinking if I encrypt the pw before hashing it will further reduce the use of a e.g. rainbow table?

Comment: No, it will not reduce the effectiveness of the rainbow table

Comment: @schroeder would you mind explaining why not?

Comment: Salts defeat the rainbow table. You've just added a small extra step.

Comment: This is a [pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is that any secure process must be able to remain secure even if the process is known. In this scheme, you've just added a step: encryption.

But you have to accept that people will know that you've added encryption and what type. This means that you've only made the process of checking passwords just one step more difficult because there is that extra step.

This means that you've only made it a little more difficult to test passwords: `hash(encrypt(password||salt))`

Your better bet is to do what is suggested for best practice: multiple rounds of hashing.

Comment: ok...so I assume my key is also stolen, so the encryption becomes a joke?

Comment: If they can steal the password table, then you have to assume they can also get the key.

Answer (score 1):

Provided a [proper password hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) is used, hashing and salting alone is sufficiently secure. Additional encryption does not add any relevant security to it.